# Perl's __SUB__ analogue for Ruby

Tags: ruby, lambda

In Perl we can use `__SUB__` to get the reference to the current subroutine. Is there analogue for Ruby?

For example let's write an anonymous factorial subroutine in Perl:

```
my $fact = sub {
    $_[0] > 1 ? $_[0] * __SUB__->($_[0] - 1) : 1;
};
```

In Ruby I'd create a named method first and then convert it to lambda:

```
def factorial(n) 
  n > 1 ? n * factorial(n - 1) : 1
end

fact = method(:factorial).to_proc
```

I feel it is not the best way to write recursive lambdas. Did I miss something?

Comment: Not sure if there's anything built-in but you could use the [y-combinator in Ruby (link)](http://www.sbf5.com/~cduan/technical/ruby/ycombinator.shtml) to avoid naming the method =)

Comment: @maerics, If you simply post that and how to use the y-combinator here, it would be an answer.

Comment: @maerics, thank you. Not exactly what I am looking for but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Ruby provides any built-in utilities that will help you perform recursion without first naming the function; however, you could [use the Y-combinator in Ruby](http://www.sbf5.com/~cduan/technical/ruby/ycombinator.shtml) to do so:

```ruby
def y_combinator(&generator)
  proc { |x|
    proc { |*args| generator.call(x.call(x)).call(*args) }
  }.call(proc { |x|
    proc { |*args| generator.call(x.call(x)).call(*args) }
  })
end

factorial = y_combinator do |callback|
  proc { |n| n > 1 ? n * callback.call(n - 1) : 1 }
end

factorial.call(5) # => 120
```